# Change header/footer in MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC4 and I am jumping directly from ASP.net 2.0? Just started learning "Music Store" Application (Razor). One thing I am always confusing is Theme header/footer. How to change them to my company custom header.

We have separate header in LAMP server (which is is PHP page) I have to that header in by calling with url like  "MyCompany.com}/inc/custom/typical_header_tall/".

Please someone explain me this. Is there any good book or article on MVC4 themes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may take a look at the `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` file which is where those sections are defined. By default when you create a new ASP.NET MVC application using some of the built-in templates in Visual Studio all views inherit from this layout file (because there's a `~/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml` file specifying the common layout).

You may read more about layouts and Razor templates in [`this blog post`](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx) from Scott Gu. They are the equivalent of content forms and master pages in the WebForms world.